# Пишу сапер но у меня есть проблема со списком!

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Я пишу сапер на python, но у меня проблема. Я хочу сделать много строчный список, а выводится однострчный!

```
import random
from random import randint
mas = [["*"], ["*"], ["*"], ["*"],
        ["*"], ["*"], ["*"], ["*"],
        ["*"], ["*"], ["*"], ["*"],
        ["*"], ["*"], ["*"], ["*"]]

array = []

n = 2
while n > 0:
    n -= 1
    a = randint(0, 15)
    if a in array:
        while True:
            a = randint(0, 15)
            if a in array:
                a = randint(0, 15)
            else:
                array.append(a)
                break
    array.append(a)
    mas[a].remove("*")
    mas[a].append("+")

print(mas)
```

Comment: Не путайте, пожалуста, представление объекта в памяти и то, как вы пишите это в тексте самой программы. Хотите многострочный вывод - печатайте по одному символу и делайте перевод строк, где надо. А не просто `print(mas)`.

Answer (score 1):

Ну печатайте так:

```py
for i in range(0, 4*4, 4):
    print(mas[i:i+4])
```

Вывод:

```
[['*'], ['*'], ['*'], ['*']]
[['*'], ['*'], ['*'], ['*']]
[['*'], ['*'], ['*'], ['+']]
[['*'], ['+'], ['*'], ['*']]
```

Или так:

```py
for i in range(0, 4*4, 4):
    print(*mas[i:i+4])
```

Вывод:

```
['*'] ['*'] ['*'] ['*']
['*'] ['*'] ['*'] ['*']
['*'] ['*'] ['*'] ['+']
['*'] ['+'] ['*'] ['*']
```

Answer (score 0):

просто визуально сделать список многострочным - не эффективно, нужно создать матрицу из двух массивов, где int[][] = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]] и уже по такому массиву ходить с координатами (x, y), где (0, 0) = 1 и т.д.

Comment: нет мне нужен вывод многострочный

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть так

```py
mas = [["*", "*", "*", "*"],
        ["*", "*", "*", "*"],
        ["*", "*", "*", "*"],
        ["*", "*", "*", "*"]]
```